# Azure Synapse Pipeline Get Metadata Last Modified Date on file instead of on folder

Tags: pipeline, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

I am trying to get the Last Modified date on the files (CSV linked service) in my repository using Get Metadata activity.

**Field List**

[image]

However, I am getting the same date/time for all of the files... the LastModified date on the folder instead of the individual files inside.

**same LastModifiedDate output example**

[image]

My design pattern is to Get the list of files and then iterate in a For Each over each item.

**Synapse Pipeline design pattern**

[image]

I am able to get the Filenames with

```
@activity('Get Metadata').output.childItems
```

I just don't see a LastModified date in the attributes of the Jason.

This code needs to go a level deeper:

```
@activity('Get Metadata').output.lastModified
```

What is the syntax I am missing to access each of the file properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get Pratik's solution to work.

I had to do the following:

A) Pass childItems to ForEach

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
```

[image]

B) On the ForEach GetMetadata2, use a copy of the dataset. Add item.name to the filename value and select the Last Modified in the Field List:

```
@item().name
```

[image: On the ForEach GetMetadata2, use a copy of the dataset. Add item.name]

C) Open the copy of the dataset and add to the filename

```
@dataset().filename
```

[image: Open the copy of the dataset and add to the filename]

Answer (score 0):

**To Get Metadata Last Modified Date on file instead of on folder Follow below steps:**

- First you need to get the list of files. using **Get metadata activity** and **field list** as `Child items`.
  [image]
- Then pass this child items to the Foreach activity to loop on that.
  [image]
- Under this foreach activity take another get metadata activity to get **Last modified** date for each file.
  [image]
  For this activity use parameterized data set with filename.
  -- Create parameter in Dataset
  [image]
  -- Use this parameter in the dataset.
  [image]
- Then append your required values in Append Variable with expression:

```json
@json(Concat('{"name": "',item().name,'",','"lastModified": "',activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified,'"}'))
```

[image]

**This will create an array with Json of filename and last modified date of each file the use it further.**

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: error: No value provided for Parameter 'filename'

I added the parameter 'filename' to the Linked Service. and then for File Path have \\MyFilePath / / @dataset().filename Preview Data does not return any results. "Please provide actual value of the parameters to preview data" 

It looks like the datasource is expecting a value for the filename. It should just grab what is in the directory.